# Group multiple or statements within an IF in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works:

```
$(".valClear").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf(".png") == -1) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
```

However this doesn't (the value is removed even if it contains .png or .jpeg), what am I doing wrong?

```
$(".valClear").each(function () {
        if (($(this).val().indexOf(".png") == -1) || ($(this).val().indexOf(".jpeg") == -1)) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that code? :)

Comment: @Heikki, looping over 10 fileuploads to see if they contain .png, .jpeg, .bmp. If they don't remove the current file.

Comment: @Dykam, this is enforced server side also, so no its not "So vulnerable in any way."

Comment: Ah, okay. Just warned. It's a common trap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing an `OR`, seems like you want an `AND`, like this:

```
$(".valClear").each(function () {
    if (($(this).val().indexOf(".png") == -1) && ($(this).val().indexOf(".jpeg") == -1)) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

With your `OR` logic, the value will likely not have either one of them, and the *other* part will be true, you want an `AND`, meaning it has neither in the value.

You can also optimize it a bit, like this:

```
$(".valClear").each(function () {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if ((val.indexOf(".png") == -1) && (val.indexOf(".jpeg") == -1)) {
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

---

To stray quite a bit from the question, and towards your actual problem...I'd actually change up how you're doing this, using an array of allowed extensions and [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to check it, like this:

```
var allowedExtensions = ["png", "jpeg", "bmp"];
$(".valClear").each(function () {
  if ($.inArray($(this).val().split('.').pop(), allowedExtensions) == -1) {
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Qvp9d/3/).  You can see from the format, this is *much* easier to expand to allow additional extensions later.

Comment: @nick - you're checking for `-1` though, which means for *this* upload (the one you're looking over) you want to check it *doesn't* have `.png` **and** *doesn't* have `.jpeg`, in any other case clear the field.  With an **or** it's always true, you want to check and make sure *neither* is true here...try it out, it'll give you the expected result.

Comment: @Nick Craver, this code keeps the .png but removes everything else that isn't a .png. It should be keeping the jpeg also

Comment: @nick - are you sure you're testing `.jpeg` and not.`jpg`?  Also make sure your code is exactly as I have above, you can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Qvp9d/

Comment: @nick - be aware of the extension variety like  `".jpg"` too!!

Comment: @ifaour - agreed, I'd actually do a `.split(".").pop()` and do an `$.inArray()`, I just didn't want to stray too far from the question here :)

Comment: @Nick Craver - check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/Qvp9d/2/) :D, hopefully this will help him understand why using && instead - happy holidays!

Comment: @ifaour - there's actually a much better way to go about it, check out the updated answer above ;)

Comment: I will be testing for about 4 different file types, i just used 2 here for breivety.

Comment: @Nick Craver - yup, this is why you got the +1..BTW add `jpg` to the list ;) and maybe the CAPITAL variant of the allowed list..just in case ;)

Comment: @Nick Craver, thanks for the many examples, I used your array version.

Comment: Regexes are starting to seem unfashionable to me around here, but I'd at least try a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) test to see if a regex against the value would be quicker than doing the array search.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `AND`:

```
($(this).val().indexOf(".png") == -1) && ($(this).val().indexOf(".jpeg") == -1)
```

If the the string ends in `.jpeg` then the first expression will evaluate to `true`.
`true OR false == true` (the second expression won't even get evaluated).

Another option is to negate the whole expression (and test for whether `.png` and `.jpeg` are *contained* rather than *not* contained):

```
!($(this).val().indexOf(".png") > -1) || ($(this).val().indexOf(".jpeg") > -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of that second `if` test. It's like saying this:

> If what you offer me for dinner is **not** roast chicken **or** it is **not** cold ham, then I'll have some

In that situation, you might get some cold ham or you might get roast chicken.  Why?  Because roast chicken is not cold ham, and because cold ham is not roast chicken. You said you're OK with whatever the kitchen has ready as long as what you get is either not roast chicken or not cold ham, so either of the two satisfies the condition.

If you phrase the qualifier with **and** instead of **or**, of course, then the kitchen will have to get creative with the left-over mashed potatoes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative for and/or conditions. If the value doesn't match the regexp then..

```
$(".valClear").each(function () {
  if ( !$(this).val().match(/\.(png|jpeg)/) ) {
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```